# ansible: Run role 'bar' against host 'B' when running role 'foo' against host 'A'

Tags: ansible

Can I run a different role against a different host as a dependency of a role?

My use case for this is to reconfigure "postfwd" on my mail server when running the "postfix" role against a new server (which will relay all mail thru the mail server).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since ansible 1.3 using [role dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies) and `delegate_to`

To run the *postfwd* role against host *mail.example.com* whenever the *postfix* role is run against **any** host, add the following to `meta/main.yml` within the *postfix* role:

```
dependencies:
  - role: postfwd
    delegate_to: mail.example.com
```